# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen bewusstlos und unbewusst?

Tags: meaning, difference

Die klingen so ähnlich, bedeuten aber nicht dasselbe. Ich verstehe, dass **bewusstlos** eher ein Zustand ist, den man in einem Zeitraum haben kann; allerdings meint **unbewusst** eine Art der Tat, die nicht bewusst geschehen wird. Stimmt es?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Beide Worte lassen sich mit *unconcious* übersetzen. Dein Verständnis stimmt. Wenn Du nach einem Unfall, aus gesundheitlichen Gründen oder von Drogen umkippst und nicht mehr ansprechbar bist, bist du in einem bewusstlosen Zustand, oder kurz: bewusstlos. Ein Synonym ist *besinnungslos*.

> Peter stürzte vom Fahrrad und schlug sich den Kopf an. Er blieb eine Zeit lang bewusstlos. Im Krankenhaus erlangte er sein Bewusstsein wieder.
>
> Problem Komasaufen: Jugendliche trinken bis zur Besinnungslosigkeit

Sich einer Sache bewusst sein bedeutet, dass Dir klar ist, dass diese Sache abläuft / von Statten geht.

> Ich bin mir bewusst, dass es einen Mangel an Pflegekräften in Deutschland gibt.  (Bescheid wissen)
>
> Ich bin bewusst nicht über die Autobahn gefahren, weil da immer Stau ist. (mit Absicht)

Umgekehrt bedeutet unbewusst, dass Du Dir nicht im Klaren über eine Sache bist.

> Peter fasst sich beim Überlegen immer unbewusst in den Bart. (automatisch)
>
> Viele Menschen haben unbewusst Vorurteile gegenüber einer anderen Personengruppe. (nicht mit Absicht / nicht wissend)

Comment: Besinnungslos kann unterschiedliche Bedeutungen haben, aber ich finde dein Beispiel als Synonym zu bewusstlos schlecht gewählt. Wer besinnungslos besoffen ist, muss nicht unbedingt bewusstlos sein, sondern hat sich selbst ggf. nur nicht unter Kontrolle. Die aus Duden dazu passende Definition: "seiner selbst nicht mehr mächtig".

Comment: Der Duden selbst listet es als Synonym. Besinnungslosigkeit ist ein anderes Wort für Bewusstlosigkeit, Ohnmacht oder Koma. Trinken bis zur Besinnungslosigkeit ist für mich etwas anderes als besinnungslos betrunken sein. Das eine ist ein Zustand, das andere beschreibt ein Adjektiv.

Answer (score 9):

*Bewusstlos* ist jemand, der überhaupt nichts mehr mitbekommt, im Englischen könnte man das mit *passed out* übersetzen, wenn man es von *unbewusst* abgrenzen will. Bewusstlose sind nach den Regeln für Erste Hilfe auf regelmäßige Atmung zu untersuchen und ein Notruf ist abzusetzen.

*Unbewusst* heißt nur, dass man einen Sachverhalt/Beweggrund gerade übersieht; die Wahrnehmung an sich ist aber nicht eingeschränkt.

Beispiel:

> Im Supermarkt greift man unbewusst eher nach den Waren in Augenhöhe als nach denen in unteren Regalen.